# Can I freeze Brownie Truffles?

Tags: freezing, chocolate-truffles

I’d like to make truffles with brownie crumbs and ganache and freeze the balls to be rolled in cocoa powder or nuts when thawed.  Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

I have not made explicitly what you're asking for, but I regularly freeze ganache, with no ill effects. Just be careful when you thaw them. Don't leave them out 'naked' in room temperature air, or you will get condensation on them.